# Changing reduced partial sum into a multiplicative function

Tags: number-theory

I have a partial sum in the form of $$\sum_{\substack{n \leq x\\k|n}} f(n)$$  for a fixed $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $f(n)$ is a multiplicative function. Is there a way to reduce this partial sum into another sum such that I can exploit the multiplicative property of the main term of the resulting sum?

Comment: $$ \sum_{n\leqslant x,k|n}f(n)=\sum_{p\leqslant\frac{x}{k}}f(pk) $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, we can write 
$$\sum_{{n\le x}\atop{k|n}}f(n)=\sum_{{pk\le x}\atop{k|pk}}f(pk)=\sum_{k\le x/p}f(pk),$$
as the requirement $k|pk$ is always met for $p,k\ne 0$.